# Drop Down Working in JSFiddle But Not Appearing On Website

Tags: html, css, nav

I coded a dropdown menu (with some help from StackOverflow users) that is now working the way I'd like it to in JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RUMQP/).

The problem is, for some reason, when I implement the code in my actual website, it doesn't work. The drop down just doesn't appear (http://www.noellesnotes.com). I thought it had something to do with the Z-Index, but I fiddled with it and the problem persists.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
ul.site-navigation {
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.site-navigation li a{
    padding: 50px 0 47px 0;
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif, Georgia;
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: rgb(82,82,82);
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

ul.site-navigation > li {
    position: relative;
    width: 125px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.site-navigation a:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(4,141,195);
    text-shadow: rgb(200, 200, 200) 1px 1px 0px;
    padding: 97px 0 0 0;
}

ul.site-navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
     height: 50px;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}

ul.site-navigation ul li {
     float: none;
     line-height: 50px;
 }

ul.site-navigation ul li a {
     font-weight: regular;
     font-size: 20px;
 }

ul.site-navigation li:hover ul {
     display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;

}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="site-navigation">
    <li><a href="/bio/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/portfolio/">Work</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: refresh your cache? I can see it (but it's not aligned perfectly)

Comment: I think she means that below `Work` that `Seventeen.com` should appear when `Work` is hovered over.

Comment: It seems to be working for me on your website

Comment: @Ishita blurfus, what browsers are you using? I'm using chrome and "Seventeen.com" is not appearing when I hove and I've refreshed my cache... Odd.

Comment: The drop down thingy appears on both firefox and chrome latest versions

Comment: @Ishita Well that is especially odd... I'm not sure why it's not appearing for me...

Comment: It's definitely appearing behind the `site-branding shadow` element. Now we just need to get it in front!

Comment: @MannfromReno Oh, so it's not up front for you as well? I thought I was going crazy. I thought changing the Z-Index would fix it, but nope...

Comment: try assigning a class to that `<ul>` like `<ul class="submenu">` so we can work directly with that element in CSS

Comment: @MannfromReno Added it to the HTML! Though I'm not sure where to go from there in terms of CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your wrapper to hide content-overflow. Either you make the wrapper respond to the Submenu on hover or you remove the `overflow: hidden;` attribute.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your website, I don't see this code there.

```
ul.site-navigation li:hover ul {
     display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;

}
```

Add it on your website's CSS, it should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, this code is there on line 703, sadly! I wish that solved it.